# How to Uplod a File using Selenium Webdriver using pycharm

Tags: selenium, file-upload, pycharm

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zoiPx.png)When I am uploading a file in `pycharm` I'm getting the below error

here is my code line for uploading the file

```
upload_file = WebDriverWait(driver, 5).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//a[normalize-space()='browse']")))
upload_file.send_keys("C:\artifact\EWV100_1.27.0-rc1.download")
```

Here I am getting this error

```
[selenium.common.exceptions.ElementNotInteractableException: Message: element not interactable]
```

Comment: Can you share the outer HTML of this `//a[normalize-space()='browse']` ?

Comment: Also, do you see `//input[@type='file']` in HTML-DOM at least once?

Comment: Please click on "enter image description here" you will be able to see my screenshot of HTML-DOM

Answer (score 0):

to upload a file using Selenium webdriver, if your web page has at least one web element with xpath `//input[@type='file']` you can directly send the keys.

```
upload_file = WebDriverWait(driver, 5).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//input[@type='file']")))
upload_file.send_keys("C:\artifact\EWV100_1.27.0-rc1.download")
```

should get the job done.

**PS:** You shouldn't write a code to click on an upload button, the above code does upload the file without having a launched OS prompt.